# Best approach to monitor schema change on Snowflake database?

Tags: snowflake-schema

Could anyone suggest best approach to monitor schema change of Snowflake database?

I would to trigger my app when any schema changes, and furthermore, I would trigger my app when any permission changes.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the last_altered column in Schemata View in Information_schema  and run a task to pull information.

Reference: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema/schemata.html

Comment: The column helps to some extend. The defect is the column cannot help to find out deleted columns.

Comment: I think a script or stored proc that queries query_history.query_text to look for "Alter table" commands should work. Be sure to filter on dates so you just pull for the dates needed.